# How to extract key and value from JSON Object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I integrated API, I want to get both key and value from API response. I stored both key and value in two separate arrays and display  inside the listview.so How to get key and value from api response.

```json
[
    { "Name": "abc"
        "Department": "Marketing",
        "EmpCode": "ABC123",
        "Salary":"20000",
        "Pincode": 100023
}]
```

I got response using this code:

```
List list = json.decode(response.body);
```

So how to get Name,department,empcode and abc,marketing separate.

Comment: This json does not seem valid. Do you always get a list with 1 object in? Then you could do `list[0]['Name']` or iterate the list if it contains more elements.

Comment: I got only one obejct in response and keys always change from backend side.so I want key sfrom response

Comment: Rohits answer seems to be what you're after then, if you don't know the keys, but want to iterate them.

Answer (score 3):

just use a forEach loop and it will extract keys and values for you which you can store according to your requirement and you don't have to worry about how many keys you have

```
response.forEach((key, value){
    print('key is $key');
    print('value is $value ');
  }
```

Comment: json.decode(response.body) .forEach((key, value){
            print('key is $key');
            print('value is $value ');
          });
: type '(dynamic, dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'

Comment: I think you are facing this error because your response is a list of objects and you can  run for each loop on object so first run a for loop to access the objects and then run these foreach loop on the object and if you have only one object inside list then directly set index = 0 and use the for Each Loop

Comment: you can also check this article for better understanding of JSON serialization https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that will hold your fields and add a fromJson method like so:

```
 class ClassName{
          ClassName(
              {this.Name,
              this.Department,
              this.EmpCode,
              this.Salary,
              this.Pincode,
             });
        
          String Name;
          String Department;
          String EmpCode;
          double Salary;
          String Pincode;
               
        ClassName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
              Name= json['Name'];
              Department= json['Department'];
              EmpCode= json['EmpCode'];
              Salary= json['Salary'];
              Pincode= json['Pincode'];
        }
    }
```

And then you could do something like that with your json that you get from the API:

```
var x = json.decode(response.body.toString());

var className = ClassName.fromJson(x);
```

Comment: I do not know How many keys will come in response